# How store Json Object to ELK using dotnet Logging

Tags: c#, .net, logging, elastic-stack, serilog

How can i store Json Object using dotnet logging interface. I'm using Serilog as provider.

With this code i never see "myObject" when i'm checking the log :

```
public CommandResult Example(MyObject myObject)
{
        try
        {
             logger.LogInformation("myObject is : ", myObject); // <== log my object as json
         }
         catch (System.Exception ex)
         {
             logger.LogError(ex, "error");
         }

         return null;
}
```

How log args object ?:

[image]

Is it possible or i should use an other way?

**----- EDIT 2018-10-22 -----**

When i log with the property {@property} I can see information on Kibana.
but i only save primitive property

WORK

```
logger.LogInformation("SendMessageToFrontEnd {@user} {@message} {@sendDate}", Model.Owner.Id, "Test", messages.SentDate);
```

NOT WORK

```
class myObject
{
  [JsonProperty("dataInt")]
  public int DataInt { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

...

var test = new myObject() { DataInt = 123, Name = "test" };
logger.LogInformation("SendMessageToFrontEnd {@user} {@message} {@sendDate}", Model.Owner.Id, test, messages.SentDate);
```

How can log JSON Object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation i fix my bug (without understand why).

But when you log to ELK is look like the field **message** has been reserved.

```
// NOT WORK
logger.LogInformation("SendMessageToFrontEnd {@user} {@message} {@sendDate}", Model.Owner.Id, test, messages.SentDate);

// WORK
logger.LogInformation("SendMessageToFrontEnd {@user} {@messageSent} {@sendDate}", Model.Owner.Id, test, messages.SentDate);
```

Ben.